# How to draw a line and drag & resize it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, draw

I want to draw a line (more accurately, an arrow) on a PictureBox control. (not draw a line to image itself)

Then, I want to grab the line, move it and resize it(change it's X,Y,X',Y') by dragging.

How can I do that?

I think, at first, I should draw a line and make the drawn line as an independent object... but I only have a concept not the practical ones..

Picture below is an example I found but cannot implement.

That's exactly what I want to make. Draw arrows, Move, Resize and Erase.

[image]
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2097/LineTracker-A-CRectTracker-like-Class-for-Lines

Comment: Without code we can't really help. begin somewhere like this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59049-simple-drawing-selection-shape-or-rubberband-shape/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this and more complicated vector drawing stuff several times in .NET. I won't provide you with the exact code, but rather the sequence of steps you need to follow. Hopefully you can pick up from there:

1. Create a new UserControl. Name it anything like `DrawingCanvas` or `ArrowsPond` or whatever.
2. Set control's `DoubleBuffered` property to `True` for smooth drawing.
3. Define a global `Class` (not `Structure`) named `Arrow` with two properties `Start` and `End` of `Point` type. Declare a global `List(Of Arrow)` to store all your arrow locations.
4. Override `OnMouseDown()`. Set a global flag named `IsMouseDown` to `True` here. Set a global variable of `Point` type named `MouseDownPos` to `e.Location`.
5. Override `OnMouseUp()`. If  `IsMouseDown` is `True`, set it to `False` and add a new `Arrow` to your list with `Start=MouseDownPos` and `End=e.Location`.
6. Override `OnMouseMove()`. If `IsMouseDown` is `True`, call `Me.Invalidate()`.
7. Override `OnPaint()` and draw all the arrows in your `List` using `Graphics.DrawLine()` method.

This was the drawing part. Now to handle resizing part:

1. In `OnMouseMove()`, if `IsMouseDown` is `False`, check if `e.Location` is close enough to any of the start or end-points in your List. You could use simple Euclidean Distance for this and set an arbitrary threshold (say 10 pixels) to define "close-enough" in a more objective way. If you find such a point, store its reference in a global variable of `Arrow` type named `ArrowUnderMouse` and set cursor shape to Resize to indicate to the user that he can now drag that point. If you do not detect any close point, set `ArrowUnderMouse` to `Nothing` and reset cursor back to `Default`. You'll need one last global variable named `IsOnHead` of `Boolean` type to keep track of whether mouse is near the head or tail of the arrow.
2. In `OnMouseMove`, if `IsMouseDown` is `True` and `ArrowUnderMouse` is not `Nothing` then instead of doing the normal stuff I listed above, set the `Start` or `End` property of `ArrowUnderMouse` to `e.Location` depending on whether `IsOnHead` and call `Invalidate()`.

This is just the skeleton of what you need to do and there are LOTS of possibilities that you'd like to play with. For drawing arrow-heads, you'll need to play with `Pen` properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LineShape` control to draw horizontal, vertical, or diagonal lines on a form or container, both at design time and at run time.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks


Dim canvas As New ShapeContainer
Dim theLine As New LineShape
' Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
canvas.Parent = Me
' Set the ShapeContainer as the parent of the LineShape.
theLine.Parent = canvas
' Set the starting and ending coordinates for the line.
theLine.StartPoint = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
theLine.EndPoint = New System.Drawing.Point(640, 480)
```

Use `PictureBox.Position.X`, `PictureBox.Position.Y`, `PictureBox1.Size.Height` and `PictureBox1.Size.Width` as X,Y coordinates when setting the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint`